# how to calculate the load time of website

Tags: css, html, web

We are making a website. And currently it size around 60 mb it contains too many photographs and we are somewhat bothered about load time of website. Is there any way to test the load website without going onair?? It consists of css, html, bootstrap, java script..

Answer (score 0):

Try "yslow" addon for firefox, you will also need firebug for this to work.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers have network statistics that will show you each HTTP request, what is it, how long it took, how large it is and so on. In Chrome you'll find it in Developer Tools (F12) and the Network tab. Reload the page and it will populate.

60 MB is huuuuuge man. You should probably make the images somewhat smaller and use a technology like lazy load to only load images that is in viewport.